# Is there a flag you can set to disable auto suggest behavior for an HTML field on iPad/iPhone/Android/etc

Tags: html, touchscreen, autosuggest

For desktop browsers I can set this on a field to disable the auto-completion list based on recent entries.

```
<input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off"/>
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However this doesn't *disable* the auto-suggestion feature of iPad / iPhone / Android / etc. which can be very frustrating if your username is a concatination of your first/last name or if your device thinks you want to upper case the first letter.

e.g. "jsmith" either becomes "Smith" because it thinks you miss-spelled it or "Jsmith" to try and be nice... neither of which is really desired.

Thus the question is... is there a way to disable this behavior on a per field basis?

Comment: sorry @icCube - no solution yet. :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are wanting to use the attribute autocorrect instead of autocomplete.  The attribute autocomplete is used for form autofill.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMWilliams - your are absolutely correct! I found the documentation on autocorrect here: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DesigningForms/DesigningForms.html

Answer (score 0):

FYI there is a bug in Chrome for Android resulting in those HTML 5 attributes not working properly. It appears to just recently have been fixed and hopefully should be released in an update soon.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303883&q=autocorrect&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Also feel free to Star the issue to help boost the ranking...